# Getting a 403 when calling a youtube Data API endpoint using oauth2

Tags: curl, google-api, youtube-api

I'm testing Youtube Data API to allow our user to upload some video to their youtube account using oauth2.

I'm trying to call the https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos endpoint with curl

I've tried with blank referrer, and I'm now trying with a restricted IP but I'm still getting a 403:

[image: https://i.postimg.cc/mZy14Dsm/stackoverflow-youtube-api-1.png]

[image]

As you can see the API seems to be enabled:

[image]

```
curl --request POST \
 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet%2Cstatus&key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX' \
 --header 'Authorization: Bearer XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX' \
 --header 'Accept: application/json' \
 --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
 --data '{"snippet":{"categoryId":"22","description":"Description of uploaded video.","title":"Test video upload."},"status":{"privacyStatus":"private"}}' \
 --compressed
```

I'm getting this output:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "usageLimits",
    "reason": "accessNotConfigured",
    "message": "Access Not Configured. YouTube Data API has not been used in project XXXXXXXXXX before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/youtube.googleapis.com/overview?project=XXX then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry.",
    "extendedHelp": "https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/youtube.googleapis.com/overview?project=XXX"
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Access Not Configured. YouTube Data API has not been used in project XXX before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/youtube.googleapis.com/overview?project=XXX then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry."
 }
```

The user's access_token seems to be working as I'm not getting a 401.
Am I using the right key, I'm starting to doubt that ? 
What don't I understand here ?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: I'm having the very same issue when trying to upload a video on Youtube. @Aikoho if you find something, please tell me.

Comment: Check under quota how much quota do you have?  Also note you only need key if you are accessing public data if your logging in a user you dont really need it.

Comment: @DaImTo thank you it could be it my limit per day was unset, I'm currently filling the form, and I will get back to you as soon as I got an answer from it.

Comment: FYI, you will also see this error message if your project's access to YouTube Data API Services was [automatically disabled after a 90 day inactivity period](https://developers.google.com/youtube/terms/developer-policies#d.-accessing-youtube-api-services).

If that is the case, you should have received a notice via email, which also contains the steps that need to be taken to regain access: please fill out and submit the [exceptions form](https://support.google.com/youtube/contact/yt_api_form?hl=en).

Comment: Thanks you a lot for this information @kynan. I'm not working for this company anymore and don't know what is the situation now, but I'll inform my former collegues about this and will let you know if this helped as soon as I've got some feedback from them.